# A string becomes immutable, I can't even remove spaces from it or modify it

Tags: javascript

friends I know that the title does not say much, but I have this blocker for several days.

In the following code everything works, but in my real code it does not, and I am unable to upload all my code to reproduce the error.

I am implementing a `middleware` in `nodejs` that verifies the role of a user and when it does this validation at the end it never enters my `if` since the condition is always negative.

Whatever I do, I am unable to `mutate` the value of `req.user.rol` (this is how it is in my original code and I cannot upload the original value because if I do a `JSON.stringify()` a circular structure is generated and generates an error)

```
 //let role = req.user.rol; my original code
 let role = data.rol; // code of this example
 console.log(role) -> 'Administrator General'
```

I have tried taking `spaces` out of this value, also tried converting it to a `json`, then to a string and back to a `json` to try to `mutate` its value, and it has not worked.

```
    let rol= req.usuario.rol;
    rol1=JSON.stringify({"rol":rol});
    let remove_spaces=JSON.parse(rol1).rol;
    remove_spaces=remove_spaces.replace(/ /g, "")
    console.log(remove_spaces,'Administrador General')
    //'Administrador General','Administrador General'
```

below the code I put in comments the output of my original code. I hope they understand me.

This is a screenshot of my original code I don't know if it gives clues to what is happening.

I want to know in this case that in my original code this variable (`rol`) is not allowed to remove spaces or modify, that is, it is equal to `Administrador General` why does it return a `false` in the comparison?

[image]

```js
    let data={
      "usuario":{
      "nombres": "yeison velez",
      "apellidos": "velez guzman",
      "ultimo_inicio_sesion": null,
       "supervisor_array_id": [
        null
      ],
     "planta_id": null,
     "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48209fe",
     "correo": "yeison_velez11@hotmail.com",
     "rol": "Administrador General",
     "__v": 0
      }
     }
    //let rol= req.usuario.rol; in my original code
    let rol= data.rol;
    rol1=JSON.stringify({"rol":rol});
    //output -> '{"rol":"Administrador General"}'
    let remove_spaces=JSON.parse(rol1).rol;
    //output ->'Administrador General'
    remove_spaces=remove_spaces.replace(/ /g, "")
    //output ->'Administrador General'

    console.log(remove_spaces,'Administrador General')
    //output ->Administrador General Administrador General

    console.log(typeof remove_spaces)
    //output ->string
    console.log(typeof 'Administrador General')
    //output ->string
    console.log(remove_spaces.length, 'Administrador General'.length)
    //output ->21 21
    console.log(remove_spaces=='Administrador General')
    //output ->false
    
   if (rol == 'Administrador General') {   //false
```

Comment: We do not need ***all your code***. Just your [mcve].

Comment: @PM77-1 my code is in nodejs .... I have it connected to a database and a web request, it is really difficult for me to upload it somewhere

Comment: We need just enough code to demonstrate your problem. Start chopping off blocks of your code until you can longer reproduce the problem, then go one step back.

Comment: @PM77-1 you can see that I debugged every line of my original code, and put the output

Comment: You can continue arguing and have your question closed. The choice is yours.

Comment: When I run this code, `let remove_spaces='Administrador General'; remove_spaces=remove_spaces.replace(/ /g, "");`, it prints `AdministradorGeneral` when I log the variable.

Answer (score 1):

To start, the comments in your snippet don't reflect what's actually happening.
When I run your snippet I get

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "replace",
> remove_spaces is undefined

This is because `rol` is undefined, because you are accessing `data.rol` instead of `data.usuario.rol`.

Once I correct that, everything works as expected:

```js
let data = {
"usuario": {
    "nombres": "yeison velez",
    "apellidos": "velez guzman",
    "ultimo_inicio_sesion": null,
    "supervisor_array_id": [
        null
    ],
    "planta_id": null,
    "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48209fe",
    "correo": "yeison_velez11@hotmail.com",
    "rol": "Administrador General",
    "__v": 0
}
}
//let rol= req.usuario.rol; in my original code
let rol = data.usuario.rol;
rol1 = JSON.stringify({ "rol": rol });
//output -> '{"rol":"Administrador General"}'
let remove_spaces = JSON.parse(rol1).rol;
//output ->'Administrador General'
remove_spaces = remove_spaces.replace(/ /g, "")
//output ->'Administrador General'

console.log(remove_spaces, 'Administrador General')
//output ->Administrador General Administrador General

console.log(typeof remove_spaces)
//output ->string
console.log(typeof 'Administrador General')
//output ->string
console.log(remove_spaces.length, 'Administrador General'.length)
//output ->21 21
console.log(remove_spaces == 'Administrador General')
//output ->false
```

I assume there's similar issue of accessing the wrong thing in your original code too